# Need regex to include hash (pound) character

Tags: regex

I am using this expression.

```
^\w+([\s-_]\w+)*$
```

I like this regex because it doesn't allow leading or trailing spaces, and it allows a dash or underscore but only without a space before or after.

It works perfectly with this:

```
CAT300 STD PKG 4
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to match this:

```
CAT300 STD PKG #4
```

I've tried everything I can think of and read dozens of articles and combed through other regex solutions. Can anyone help? I am stumped.

Comment: Err.. Add it to your character class.

Comment: Were the articles you read about regex :D ? Have you considered using a tool like RegexBuddy to help you compose your expressions? It might have led you to a quick solution in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to your character class:

```
/^\w+([\s-_#]\w+)*$/
```